# nvidia-340 driver and (x)ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

According to `ubuntu-drivers devices` I have this:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:0c.0/0000:02:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000647sv0000106Bsd000000BCbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : G96M [GeForce 9600M GT]
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

When trying to install it (`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`), though, I get this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-340 : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm on Xubuntu 19.04, on an old MacBook Pro from 2009.

How to get around this problem? Can it be done? Thx for any hints.

Comment: Please try `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt full-upgrade` first the try installing the driver.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1167469/cant-install-nvidia-driver-430-on-ubuntu-18-04-dell-inspiron-15-5000-gaming

Comment: forgive me all...I should have made sure that at lease sudo apt update does finish without errors and warnings. it works now, not knowing what exactly was helping. thx for looking at this!