# Can't install nvidia driver 430 on Ubuntu 18.04 (Dell Inspiron 15 5000 Gaming)

Tags: 18.04, package-management, nvidia-geforce

I can't find a solution to my problem. I can't install the latest nvidia driver on my laptop (Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming) with Ubuntu 18.04. I always have that error message :

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

[image]

Comment: Please try running `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt full-upgrade` first then try installing the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try fixing the broken packages and updating your system first by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install -f && sudo apt full-upgrade
```

After that, please reboot your system and install your drivers using the `ubuntu-drivers` tool by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then finally, please reboot your system.

---

If the first command fails to fix your broken packages, please follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501) then try installing your drivers afterwords.

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: @bouledepoisson I am glad it helped.